# Top level menu doesn't work on Planning Components Visualizer

Tags: rviz, arm-navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I attended the IROS 2011 workshop on motion planning and went through the tutorials. I wanted to do it again myself and haven't had any problems until I tried to select commands from the top level menu on Planning Components Visualizer. I don't think I had any issues at the workshop just right-clicking "Command..." to display the menu, but it doesn't work on my work environment. I followed the tutorial instructions (http://www.kavrakilab.org/sites/default/files/iros2011_ros_ompl_tutorial.pdf). Do I need to do something else to display the menu other than launching the visualizer at the beginning of Section 6? I ran roswtf and didn't see any errors (although there was 1 warning as below):

```
$ roswtf
Loaded plugin tf.tfwtf
No package or stack in context
================================================================================
Static checks summary:

No errors or warnings
================================================================================
Beginning tests of your ROS graph. These may take awhile...
analyzing graph...
... done analyzing graph
running graph rules...
... done running graph rules
running tf checks, this will take a second...
... tf checks complete

Online checks summary:

Found 1 warning(s).
Warnings are things that may be just fine, but are sometimes at fault

WARNING The following nodes are unexpectedly connected:
 * /ompl_planning->/rosout (/rosout)
 * /planning_components_visualizer->/rosout (/rosout)
 * /pr2_test_right_arm_kinematics->/rosout (/rosout)
 * /rviz_planning_components->/rosout (/rosout)
 * /wall_clock_server->/rosout (/rosout)
 * /planning_scene_validity_server->/rosout (/rosout)
 * /trajectory_filter_server->/rosout (/rosout)
 * /rob_st_pub->/rosout (/rosout)
 * /pr2_test_left_arm_kinematics->/rosout (/rosout)
 * /environment_server->/rosout (/rosout)
```

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04.3 (x86-64) with kernel 2.6.32-34 and using ROS Electric with arm_navigation 1.0.6 and visualization 1.6.4.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11581/top-level-menu-doesn%27t-work-on-planning-components-visualizer/) by [tyama](https://answers.ros.org/users/1237/tyama/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2011-10-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [egiljones](https://answers.ros.org/users/82/egiljones/) on 2011-10-18**:
Try doing an rm * in the .rviz directory in your home directory.  I've seen that fixed problems where interactive markers aren't working at all.

**Comment by [tyama](https://answers.ros.org/users/1237/tyama/) on 2011-10-18**:
Thanks for your quick reply. Yes, I selected the "Interact" tab on Rviz, and the markers showed up. The status of "Interactive Markers" was OK. But, none of the markers weren't working.

**Comment by [egiljones](https://answers.ros.org/users/82/egiljones/) on 2011-10-18**:
That's all you should need to do.  Are you sure that you've selected the "Interact" tab at the top of Rviz - none of the interactive markers will work if you don't select that tab.  Are any of the other interactive markers working in the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I ended up reinstalling the visualization stack, but everything works fine now. Thank you very much for your help, egiljones!

---

Originally posted by [tyama](https://answers.ros.org/users/1237/tyama/) with karma: 16 on 2011-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0